# -bash: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: c++, bash, compiler-errors, g++

I found a few open issues on this error, but none was relevant.

I wrote the simplest C++ code on my VM (*Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS*, `sudo virt-what` output is `vmware`
):

**z.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
        std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

and compiled with `g++ z.cpp`. When trying to call `./a.out` I get the error in the Q description, i.e.:

> -bash: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

When compiling a not-so-different C-code:

**q.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
        puts("hello world");
        return 0;
}
```

with `gcc q.c` I get no problems and the output of `./a.out` is, as expected `"hello world"`

---

This is my `dpkg --list | grep compiler`:

```
ii  g++                                          4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6                                    i386         GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-4.8                                      4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04                                i386         GNU C++ compiler
ii  gcc                                          4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6                                    i386         GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.8                                      4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04                                i386         GNU C compiler
ii  hardening-includes                           2.5ubuntu2.1                                        all          Makefile for enabling compiler flags for security hardening
ii  libllvm3.5:i386                              1:3.5-4ubuntu2~trusty2                              i386         Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, runtime library
ii  libxkbcommon0:i386                           0.4.1-0ubuntu1                                      i386         library interface to the XKB compiler - shared library
```

---

The problem is clearly in the g++ compiler, since the C-code (`q.c`) which runs fine when compiled by `gcc`, fails to run when compiled by `g++`. However, I have no idea what in the compiler exactly could be wrong

---

`file a.out = a.out: ELF 32-bit MSB  executable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.10, not stripped`

---

Already answered it, but for the sake of the question's completeness, here is the last puzzle piece that made the difference (although I didn't think of checking this when I first posted the Q):

```
alias g++='/opt/Cross_Tools/powerpc-linux-gnu/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-g++'
```

Comment: That error comes up when you have a 32-bit application trying to be executed in a 64-bit system, but that doesn't seem to help you.. I am also wondering if the [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) site would offer more help to you than SO.

Comment: @CIsForCookies: Can you paste the output of `file a.out`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem...

The g++ command was indeed making a 32-bit application (as can be seen by the output of `file a.out`). The reason is that I had an alias I wasn't aware of:

```
alias g++='/opt/Cross_Tools/powerpc-linux-gnu/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-g++'
```

which made my `g++ z.cpp` command not use the actual `/usr/bin/g++` but the cross-compiler. When compiling with `make z` the `a.out` was fine.